# What is Google API Discovery?

Tags: python, rest, google-api-discovery

I am having trouble understanding the concept of “API discovery” as used in Google products/services.  Here’s some Python code that uses the said discovery service to access Google Cloud Vision:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
… 
API_DISCOVERY_FILE = 'https://vision.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'
hlh = httplib2.Http()
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
credentials.authorize(hlh)
service = build(serviceName='vision', version='v1', http=hlh, discoveryServiceUrl=API_DISCOVERY_FILE)
service_request = service.images().annotate(body={ <more JSON code here> })
```

Here’s another bit of Python code that also accesses Google Cloud Vision, but does not use API discovery *and works just fine*:

```
import requests
…
ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate'
response = requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL,
    data=make_image_data(image_filenames),
    params={'key': api_key},
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

What I can’t wrap my head around is this question: You need to know the details of the API that you are going to be calling so that you can tailor the call; this is obvious.  So, how would API discovery help you at the time of the call, *after you have already prepared the code for calling that API*?

PS: I did look at the following resources prior to posting this question:

https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/getting_started

https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846841/what-is-discovery-based-in-rest-api) answered question but would appreciate additional insight.

Comment: Now switch API versions, dynamically. The discovery path will potentially redirect you to a different URL if Google feels that's needed for a new version. Your hardcoded URL path on the other hand..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you. I see, so the discovery service helps with changes to endpoints.  Does it provide information about changes to the format of the API call? (I.e. arguments required, nature of the return value.)

Comment: I don't know, I've not studied their discovery API in-depth. It certainly states that machine-discoverability of the APIs is a goal; e.g. you should be able to build some kind of GUI that lets you explore the APIs that Google offers with the discovery API. How much detail the API provides however, I haven't studied.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why not, what's been holding you up? :)

Comment: Plenty of things. Like moderator duties and work and family and so on. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I lack the knowledge of the Google API you are mentioning.

> You need to know the details of the API that you are going to be
>   calling so that you can tailor the call; this is obvious.

In theory to me this is only required for the very first call, which would be the call to a starting service which would for instance list a number of resources. From there on you can have branches to underlying resources and their allowed methods (verbs if you will). So this example illustrated a tree like structure. If you provide a GUI to navigate through this discoverability in a generic way, a person would then be able to decide what to do.

In practice this is kind of hard to do once you have vast amounts of resources and all sorts of interrelationships between them.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer this question; your insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Look at this for more in depth answers. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170695/what-is-the-need-for-discoverability-in-a-rest-api-when-the-clients-are-not-ad

Comment: Yet another huge thank you - the discussion in that link is exactly what I was after.  As you also state, the "first API call" must be human-tailored, but following that, the discovery API holds your hand and facilitates the interaction. At least that's what I am understanding.

Comment: Yup, correct. But ofcourse you can code a Machine Learning AI to replace the human ;) Lots of trials and errors though.

Comment: I am still not understanding something: even after the `build()`, the API call is hardcoded like this: `service.images().annotate(body...)` - so, what does the `build()` call buy me (other than providing the top root `service` for the call tree)?

Comment: You mean when you are building the client side?

Comment: Yes on the client side.

Comment: You would do one hard coded call. With that call the API tells you there are resources x, y , z. So on client side you do a for loop. For each resource you display x, y, z links. User clicks on x, now you do the call on x. API now tells you that for this x you can do a (http verb) post, put, delete etc. with the arguments. Now on the client you create links for each verb and optionally the arguments that need to be passed. Etc etc.

Comment: Thank you.  Now understand your earlier comments about needing AI! :)